Are there any exceptions where errors are subracted
Can errors ever be subracted?
Any exceptional case where errors are subracted in measurement, like    in relative error, percentage error,etc
Like whenever we calculate relative error in x/x+y we subract x+y from x instead of adding it
Why this is done,,, any specific               reasons about it?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
